# How to change upload text language codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter 3.1 . 
How to change upload text language ?

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" />
```

I want to change `Choose File - No file chosen` default English language to other.
I tried this but not worked.

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" value="new language" />
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTM52.jpg)

Comment: Codeigniter based on English. If you want custom text you need to do it manually. Framework will not support

Comment: Please see the update. @AbdullaNilam

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$file = $_FILE['file'];
if(empty($file))
{
    echo "Custom Error message";
}
```

---

**Or with system file edit**

path - `'system/language/english/upload_lang.php'`
Line 47

```
$lang['upload_no_file_selected'] = 'You did not select a file to upload.';
```

Comment: check system file Edit. You can change text of that

Comment: I can't find any word like `choose file` . I add a image see above.